# Opencv library on AIDE

Tags: opencv, aide-ide

I'm new with android programming and I want to code and compile an app based on opencv library and I want to do that from my tablet using AIDE, but I don't know how to setup opencv library in AIDE. Can anyone help me?

Comment: I believe it has already been discussed somewhere here how to add libraries to your project....

Comment: best jar file https://github.com/rajamalw/opencv-android-gradle/raw/master/jar/opencv-android.jar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go [download the .jar](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/o/Downloadopencvlibrary243jar.htm) (link to Java2). Create a `libs` folder in your app's directory and put the jar in it. Then go back to AIDE, open your project and navigate to the libs folder. Long press the jar. When the dialogue pops up asking if you what to do click "add library to project." Close AIDE, because for some reason it doesn't recognize the library until you restart it. Open your project again and you can now use any opencv class in your project by using the correct import statement.